# I can not find my garbage [19.1]

Tags: files, usb-drive, trash

I need to access and restore files from a USB drive's trash folder using the the terminal.

I moved some files from a USB drive to the trash and I need to get them back. The Files GUI isn't any good for it "Items in the trash may not be modified" and "Could not determine the original location of 'My file'". Doing it from the command line also did not work. Where is my trash?

Comment: You state 19.1?  There was no Ubuntu 19.1 release so what is the 19.1?  Ubuntu 19.10 however is EOL (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-July/000258.html) so you should *release-upgrade* asap if you're using 19.10, as Ubuntu 19.10 is now off-topic on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless youn question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: My bad, I thought 19.10 and 19.1 could be used interchangeably. I will update soon

Comment: The Ubuntu 19.10 means the 2019-October release, 19.1 would mean 2019-January of which there is no such release & you've got a fake, or something very different.

Answer (score 2):

The trash for each disk partition and USB device is in that device's local Trash (`.trash-1000`) folder.

- Each partition, device, etc, has it's own Trash folder. The system does not waste resources copying files to a central Trash location. That would be annoying every time you wanted to delete, say, a movie ("*Why does it take 10 minutes to put my movie in the Trash?*").
- Your Desktop Trash shows ALL the currently available Trash folders together. You don't need to switch between them.
- Emptying The Trash will delete the contents of only the currently-available Trash folders (currently-mounted partitions and devices). Unplugged USB sticks, for example, won't have their Trash contents deleted.

Bottom line: Re-insert your USB stick, and your files should re-appear in the Trash.

Usage note: Some folks complain that their USB storage keeps decreasing. They deleted all those movies, but only a few GB are available! You guessed it: They didn't Empty Their Trash while the device was plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I did it by going into the USB drive, doing CTRL+H to show hidden files, going into the .trash-1000 folder, and moving my files from there to my desktop! Thanks everyone for helping!